# Directory manipulation without root access

Tags: android, adb, root

I am working on an automation solution and as part of my code, I have to create a directory.

I used to do `adb shell mkdir /data/data/com.apkname/files/` following an `adb root` command.

However, when I try to do it without  adb root, it does not seem to be working. Some of the production Android devices have root disabled. I am trying to figure out how to do it without Root access. Is is possible?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding directories, you should depend on SDK provided methods. Take a look at [`Context.getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).

Comment: One thing to understand here is that I am not doing apk programming. I am communicating with device on ADB. so context.getFilesDir() is not something that I can do here. My code is c# automation

Comment: You cannot access application data for third party applications without rooting afaik (and it would probably be quite a secutiry issue if you could). If it is not your app, you shouldn't access it - at least not that way. If you explain your exact usecase someone might provide a workaround :)

Comment: If it is not your app and the device is secured, there's nothing you can do.  If it is your app, and it is a debug build you can use the run-as tool to get a shell as the owning userid, and accomplish what you want from there.  Otherwise if it needs to be under your release key, you can build another Activity into a temporary version of the app which simply creates this path, and use an Intent to launch that activity.  For that matter, if you really want you can build an ssh (or unix socket) server into the app, use that to get a shell as the app's userid, and then do whatever you want.

Comment: This is actually not my app. so I think my  options are limited. Thanks :)

Comment: If it's not your app, why are you needing to create a directory within it's private storage, and how would you be expected to make use of the result?  This seems like it should be the job of the app's developer.

Comment: Well, this app is produced by another team and it is packaged as it is. But has a hack, they said of you want to tweak the behavior a little bit than we can drop our config files into this /file/ folder after making it. But it sounds like apk should come with empty /file/ directory already so that we are only responsible of dropping the file into it.

Comment: Yes, and they are going to need to either give you (and everybody else) rights to that.  Or do a shared user ID with you.  Or give you a debug apk where you can use the run-as tool (unless you are on the release of last year where that was temporarily broken).  Perhaps you could negotiate handing them the configuration or config file with an Intent, or even reading it from the External Storage - assuming of course that this is test code and not really production.  Emulators are rooted if that helps you.  Or you could strip their certificates, add your own code, and re-sign yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `run` command with `as` as follows

```
adb shell
$ run-as package.name
```

Now that you will reach inside the specified application's data folder with all access.